# MS Word 2010: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-word-2010, runtime-error

In MS Word 2010, I'm getting an error when using a macro to call a subroutine contained in another template:

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

This pops up when I run the macro that calls a subroutine, called ShadeRow, to change the background of the current table row. ShadeRow is contained in a template, called MainProject.dotm, that is loaded at startup (listed in the Global Templates and Add-Ins dialog box) but isn't the template of TableReference.docm, the document running the macro (i.e. TableReference.docm uses a template other than MainProject.dotm).

This macro used to work (used to find ShadeRow), and now it isn't. Furthermore, I've added MainProject.dotm to TableReference.docm's Available References in the VBA interface, but I still get the same error. I also copy-pasted ShadeRow into TableReference.docm's VBA module, and the macro *still* can't find it.

Does anyone know why this error is persisting, when (1) MainProject.dotm (and therefore ShadeRow) auto-loads when Word starts up, (2) I've loaded MainProject.dotm in TableReference.docm's Available References, and (3) I've even copy-pasted ShadeRow into TableReference.docm?

Comment: Something that just occurred to me is that TableReference.docm's template is not a dotm. It's a dotx. Would that have something to do with it? Can a dotx accommodate docm's? An experiment when I return home. I'll post an update here unless someone has other thoughts.

Comment: Well, just converted my dotx to a dotm and the problem is still there. So that wasn't the solution. Any ideas, everyone?